# debian/ubuntu python /bin/python3

Tags: python, ubuntu, debian

Does anybody know why and how python have some binaries and symlinks in /bin ?

```
root@logs ~ # ls -al /bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 May 23  2020 /bin/python3 -> python3.8
root@logs ~ # dpkg -S /bin/python3
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /bin/python3
root@logs ~ # dpkg -S /bin/python3.8
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /bin/python3.8
```

Comment: bin is supposed to have binaries... that's how you can call python in your terminal. Also I don't think stackoverflow is the best place for your answer

Comment: are you sure that /bin and /usr/bin are not the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

- Debian (and moreso Ubuntu) has been trying to push "UsrMerge" (where `/bin` is really just a symlink to `/usr`/bin`, as on modern systems there is usually little reason to have them separate) for a while
- `python3` is a compatibility symlink to the actual version of the Python3 interpreter. (as it *mostly* doesn't matter whether you are running Python3.6 or Python3.8)

```sh
user@machine:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster

user@machine:~$ ls /bin/python3*
/bin/python3  /bin/python3.7  /bin/python3.7m  /bin/python3m
user@machine:~$ realpath /bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3.7
user@machine:~$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/python3.7
python3.7-minimal: /usr/bin/python3.7
user@machine:~$
```